# ngStyle for specific condition

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngfor, ng-style

```
<h4 *ngFor="let x of textAddedList" 
    [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor:textAddedList.length>2?'grey':'transparent'}">
    {{x}}
</h4>
```

I want to apply the grey styling only after the 2 entries, but when I apply this logic it applies to all instead after 2nd line. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with `index` in `*ngFor`. As the index of array starts with 0, for the rows after the second row, the index are greater than 1:

```
<h4
  *ngFor="let x of textAddedList; let i = index"
  [ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor: i > 1 ? 'grey' : 'transparent' }"
>
  {{ x }}
</h4>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubxxdj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> Output

[image]

Comment: If you only want to change the background-color you can use also `[style.background-color]="i>1?'grey':null"`. See that in this case Angular only add style when the condition is fullfilled. NOTE: using ngStyle with a property that use a "-" you can enclosed by `'`: `[ngStyle]="{'background-color':i > 1 ? 'grey' : 'transparent'}"`